# Jabref -- entries imported from jstor still marked as incomplete

Tags: bibliographies, import, jabref

When I import references from either the jstor website or through jabref front end, they all show up as red (i.e. incomplete). Specifically, "Journal title" is not present in the required field.

The really weird thing is, when I cite these references, they all show up complete. So where is "journal title" stored in my bib entry?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Show how you call your `bib` file and show us a small part of your `bib` file containing a red marked book. You can use package `filecontents` (more type `texdoc filecontents`) to include the `bib` file in your MWE.

Comment: Do you happen to use Biblatex mode? Standard BibTeX format has `journal` as the name of that field, but JabRef in `biblatex` mode expects `journaltitle`.

Comment: JabRef's 'completeness' measure is only very basic. It simply checks if certain fields are completed, and does not allow for possible 'either/or' cases (such as `editor` and `author` for many types). As such, it's at best an aid to you checking properly.

Answer (score 4):

JabRef's 'completeness' measure is only very basic. It simply checks if certain fields are completed, and does not allow for possible 'either/or' cases (such as editor and author for many types). As such, it's at best an aid to you checking properly.